# Similar functionality on multiple pages

Tags: layout, task-flow

Does it make sense to carry similar functionality on two different pages?

In my case our team is considering allowing images (which are versions of an asset) in a gallery to be commented and approved. The gallery is primarily for referencing images for artists and approval/commenting is secondary for clients.

Clients are expected to go to an asset breakdown page, that will allow them to see all versions of an asset and do approval/commenting here. We suggest this because they may require a history of all image versions before they can commit to finalizing the asset.

My feeling is that carrying the same functionality (but presenting different secondary actions/information) on two pages may be confusing for clients.

Thoughts? Am I making sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as you suspect, the problem is with the "similar" (as opposed to "the same").

If you repeat part of the UI on different pages, from the users point of view it just stays in place; it is not "seen again, somewhere else". That obviously creates a strong expectation of perfect consistency. Because of that, even minor changes of the repeated part of the UI will be *very* confusing.

That applies similarily when a seemingly same UI is shown *again* later in the interactionn, even if in a less critical way.